# moved to left and right after click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, jquery-animate

My code does not work. What I want is to move my pagination to the left and to the right after `#prev_pag` and `#next_pag` are clicked on. I don't know why this code isn't working?

**EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/szVKD/

JS code:

```
$('#next_pag').click(function() {
        $('#pagination').animate({
            marginLeft: '-=100px'
        },
        500);
    });
    $('#prev_pag').click(function() {
        $('#pagination').animate({
            marginLeft: '+=100px'
        },
        500);
    });
});
```

Comment: i think you need to use `left` instead of `marginLeft`

Comment: Well done for including a jsfiddle, but it would be nice if it actually showed some content and demonstrated the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#next_pag').click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault(); //prevent the default behaviour
        $('#pagination').animate({
            left: '-=100px'
        },
        500);
    });
    $('#prev_pag').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent the default behaviour
        $('#pagination').animate({
            left: '+=100px'
        },
        500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to animate not 'marginLeft' but 'left';
**EXAMPLE:** 
http://www3.montonfashion.com/js/slider/carouselPP.js
http://www3.montonfashion.com/et/waistcoat-willy.html

Answer (score 0):

you nedd to play with `left` not `marginleft`...[**see here**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
$('#next_pag').click(function() {
        $('#pagination').animate({
            left: '-=100px'
        },
        500);
    });
    $('#prev_pag').click(function() {
        $('#pagination').animate({
            left: '+=100px'
        },
        500);
    });
});
```